# How to iterate through columns in awk

Tags: awk

I have a short script that does what I want, however I want to apply the script to each column in the file (regardless of how many columns I have)

Input file (tab delimited):

```
1/2:17,6:23:85:85,0,370 0/0:51,6:57:17:0,17,1359    0/0:3,0:3:9:0,9,99
0/0:3,0:3:0:.:.:0,0,38  0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,33  0/1:1,2:3:26:0|1:13813_T_G:81,0,26
./.:2,0:2:.:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,33  0/1:1,2:3:26:0|1:13813_T_G:81,0,26
./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   1/1:0,4:4:12:131,12,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0
1/1:0,2:2:6:1|1:14590_G_A:90,6,0    0/0:3,0:3:9:.:.:0,9,98  0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,30
```

Assuming that:

0/1, 0/2, 1/2 = HET

0/0 = ?REF

1/1, 2/2 = HOM

else = unknown

Desired output (based on first three characters of each column):

```
1/2:17,6:23:85:85,0,370 0/0:51,6:57:17:0,17,1359    0/0:3,0:3:9:0,9,99  HET ?REF    ?REF
0/0:3,0:3:0:.:.:0,0,38  0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,33  0/1:1,2:3:26:0|1:13813_T_G:81,0,26  ?REF    ?REF    HET
./.:2,0:2:.:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,33  0/1:1,2:3:26:0|1:13813_T_G:81,0,26  unknown ?REF    HET
./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   1/1:0,4:4:12:131,12,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   unknown HOM unknown
1/1:0,2:2:6:1|1:14590_G_A:90,6,0    0/0:3,0:3:9:.:.:0,9,98  0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,30  HOM ?REF    ?REF
```

I've written a script that takes the first column and spits out the correct HET/?REF/HOM/unknown:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{if(($1 ~ /0\/1/) || ($1 ~ /1\/2/) || ($1 ~ /0\/2/)) print $1,"HET"; \
 else if(($1 ~ /1\/1/) || ($1 ~ /2\/2/)) print $1,"HOM"; \
 else if($1 ~ /0\/0/) print $1,"?REF"; \
 else print $1,"unknown";}' inputfile
```

This gives me the following:

```
1/2:17,6:23:85:85,0,370 HET
0/0:3,0:3:0:.:.:0,0,38  ?REF
./.:2,0:2:.:.:.:0,0,0   unknown
./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0   unknown
1/1:0,2:2:6:1|1:14590_G_A:90,6,0    HOM
```

So far so good. Now, I want to iterate through each column using the above script and then print the correct REF/HET/HOM in sequential order as shown below i.e genotype1 matches coded1 and genotype2 matches coded2 etc.

```
genotype1   genotype2   genotype3   coded1  coded2  coded3
1/2:17,6:23:85:85,0,370 0/0:51,6:57:17:0,17,1359    0/0:3,0:3:9:0,9,99  HET ?REF    ?REF
```

This is where I get stuck I'm afraid! I'm not sure how to loop through each column...

Please go easy, I'm a clinician and not a bioinformatician!
E

Comment: Looping through the columns, can be done with `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {... }`, Where NF is the Number of Fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is slightly different approach, may be easier to maintain

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"
              map["0/1"]=map["1/2"]=map["0/2"]="HET"
              map["1/1"]=map["2/2"]="HOM"
              map["0/0"]="?REF"}

       NR==1 {print; next}  # if you have a header, if not remove
             {printf "%s", $0
              for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
                  t=substr($i,1,3);
                  printf "%s", OFS (t in map?map[t]:"unknown")}
              print ""}' file
```